# PHP preg_replace non-greedy trouble

Tags: php, regex, regex-greedy

I've been using the following site to test a PHP regex so I don't have to constantly upload:
http://www.spaweditor.com/scripts/regex/index.php

I'm using the following regex:

```
/(.*?)\.{3}/
```

on the following string (replacing with nothing):

```
Non-important data...important data...more important data
```

and preg_replace is returning:

```
more important data
```

yet I expect it to return:

```
important data...more important data
```

I thought the ? is the non-greedy modifier.  What's going on here?

Comment: What settings are you using on the site you linked? I just tried it and got back "Non-important data" as I expected. Your regular expression is finding the first match, and grabbing as little as it can before it can find a `...`.

Comment: @Doug Neiner: On his website link, make sure you select `preg_replace` in the last section. I was able reproduce the OP's results this way.

Comment: Ah, very true. Picked the wrong one.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your non-greedy modifier is working as expected. But `preg_match` replaces *all* occurences of the the (non-greedy) match with the replacement text (`""` in your case). If you want only the first one replaced, you could pass `1` as the optional 4th argument (limit) to `preg_replace` function ([PHP docs for preg_replace](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)). On the website you linked, this can be accomplished by typing `1` into the text input between the word "Flags" and the word "limit".

Comment: +1 @Asaph, great answer. I had chosen `preg_match` instead of `preg_replace` when I tried out the link, so it through me of the scent. You are of course completely correct in your answer!

Answer (score 0):

just an actual example of @Asaph solution. In this example ou don't need non-greediness because you can specify a count.
replace just the first occurrence of @ in a line with a marker

```
 $line=preg_replace('/@/','zzzzxxxzzz',$line,1);
```